# Algorithm for iterating through all strings of shortest lengths?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm making a URL shortener, and I want to use the shortest possible string for each given URL. Each URL will have a different expiry date.

For example, let's submit URLs that get shortened to the following list:

`a, b, c, ..., z, 0 ..., 9, aa, ab, ac, ... a9, ba`

Then, say `c` expires, so the next URL should be shortened to `c` instead of `bb`, since `c` is shorter and is not taken.

What data structure would be good for keeping track of this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a fun problem. You need several data structures for this. This is what I would do.

1) A hash table, with short URLs as keys, and all the URL info (full URLs, expiry times, etc) as values.

2) A min-heap of expired URLs. This would allow you to quickly grab and reuse the  shortest URL available.

3) A string, to keep track of the longest short URL in use. This allows you to quickly generate a new URL if there are no expired ones that are shorter.

4) Something to keep track of expiry times, so you can expire URLs efficiently. It could be hash table in the form of Date-->ShortURL, with the ordered keys, so you can easily get the urls that expire next.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a priority queue whose comparator has nested rules, the first being a flag on empty or taken, the second being on the string. Remember that a PQ keeps your most-sought-for objects on top of the queue. Your object as a result should be a composite of the string name and a boolean flag.

Comment: A PQ wouldn't work for any number of entries though, there would have to be a limit.

Comment: Not that I know of. A PQ is [unbounded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) unless it's programmatically set to some limit.

Comment: You're right actually, there's an easy way around that. One other issue though is that if a large amount of elements are added, then they're in the PQ forever, taking up a lot of space. I guess I could routinely clear them.

Comment: Again, this is app-dependent. If a simple counter that keeps track of the expired URLs is maintained, then the PQ can grow to a certain LIMIT only. Once the number of expired URLs exceeds LIMIT, we can remove/poll objects.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use 2 heaps.

1. A min heap for unused urls, where the min value is the url.
2. A min heap for used urls, where the min value is the number of seconds since 1/1/1970 (long value).

When you need a new url, pull from the top of the heap 1. When a url expires, pull the url from the heap 2 and insert it into heap 1.